# How to make NaN divide by Nan in two data frames and checking for a condition to be marked "TRUE" all the time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]**I am trying to divide two data frames which contain nan values and when I check it for a condition I am getting the result as False but I want the result when dividing two nan values and comparing to a condition to be TRUE all the time**

Comment: What should be the result if only one of the values is NaN?

Comment: @SergeBallesta if dataframe 1 has a nan  then dataframe 2 will also have the nan at the same location in our data sets. So we will never have a case with only one NAN in one data frame,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `NaN/NaN` gives `NaN`, and `NaN>1` is false, after the division, you could try to fill `NaN` values with 2, for example or with any number greater than 1, using [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), to mask as you want:

```
df1.div(df2).fillna(2)
```

---

**Example:**

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'X':[np.nan,2],'Y':[2,1]})
df1
#     X  Y
#0  NaN  2
#1  2.0  1

df2=pd.DataFrame({'X':[np.nan,2],'Y':[1,7]})
df2
#     X  Y
#0  NaN  1
#1  2.0  7

df1.div(df2)    
#     X         Y
#0  NaN  2.000000
#1  1.0  0.142857

df1.div(df2).fillna(2)>1
#       X      Y
#0   True   True
#1  False  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe write a function for it instead of dividing them like (slightly pseudocode)

```
def nanChecker(a, b):
  if a == NaN && b == NaN:
    return true
  return false
```

Comment: I have to perform a divide and then check for greater than condition. So when I do that NaN/NaN >1 is giving me False but I need it to be TRUE

Comment: Ah, i see. I feel like you should take a step back and see if there's a better approach to solving your problem further up the line, you current one seems to be quite strange, and that there should be a more elegant solution.

Do you really need to divide the two numbers? Is there no better way of doing that using a callback? Could you add another extra function before the division and do the parsing in two steps instead of one? Could you do some preprocessing on the datasets to limit the amount of edge cases (an example would be to replace the nan values with -1)?

Answer (score 0):

this is very easy, using element wise operation

```
import pandas as pd     

data1 = [(None, 2), (2, 1)]
data2 = [(None, 1), (2, 7)]
dataFrame1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
dataFrame2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
divisionResults = dataFrame1.div(dataFrame2)

resultFrame = (divisionResults>1)  | (dataFrame1.isnull() & (dataFrame2.isnull()))
```